# How to delete a facebook app request using curl

Tags: curl, oauth, facebook-graph-api

The way I am trying to do this is:

```
curl -X DELETE 'https://graph.facebook.com/109704795785446?access_token=138205092919756|2.AQCHtZ2hrwzjiGaZ.3600.1307545200.0-100002462848072|4m2baU7y6RGevbgfFbGV8j05t2A'
```

The access_token is valid as I use the same to get all the app requests for a particular user.

The error that I get is:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#1) Invalid parameter: Unknown error"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're either missing or putting the request id in incorrectly. This is the format:

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>_<USER_ID>]?
access_token=[USER or APP ACCESS TOKEN]
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, then tried it inside a batch request and it worked.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

(it's just a workaround though, i think it should work as a single DELETE request as well...)